# Windows CE 3.0: error when I try to create object to can copy files:

Tags: vbscript, windows-ce

I want to create a VBS script for a Windows CE device to copy some files from a SD card to a network folder. But I get this error: Error ActiveX component can't create object: 'CreateObject'

This is  the code:

```
' Declaration of variable
Dim objFileSystem

' Create object for filesystem access
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Copy folder
objFileSystem.CopyFolder "\storage card2\*", "\\PlcServer\csv"
' Deallocate filesystem object
Set objFileSystem = Nothing
```

The problem is when I try to create the FileSystemObject object.

Do I need to register or do something in the Windows CE device to can use this script?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Windows CE supports VBScript out of the box. Maybe the addition of this [VB runtime](http://www.cebeans.com/runtime/runtime.htm) will help. No guarantees. VB isn't VBScript.

Comment: [Python for Windows CE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonce/) may provide an alternative solution.